# Center UICollectionViewCells in Swift 4

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, swift4

I am working on UICollectionView and so far I have done it pretty well. I am stuck at UIViewLayout where I want to make the cells to be in center.
I am trying to make my UICollectionView Cells center. Please see the image's below. Image 1 is what I achieved through the code below Image 2 is what I want it to be like. Please help guys. TIA
Image - 1
[image: Image 1]

Image - 2
[image: Image 2]

Take a look at my code snippet.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var sizingCell = StateCollectionViewCell()
var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "California", 
"Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", 
"Idaho", "Indiana", "Lowas", "Kansas", "New Jersey", "Mexico", 
"Missori", "Montana", "Newada", "New York", "Maine", "Maryland", 
"Kentchuky"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a 
nib.
setupCollectionView()

  let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! 
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout
  layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 15, bottom: 10, 
  right: 20)
  layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
  layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
  }

  // Mark: - Initializing a collectionView and addint it to the VC's 
  current view
  func setupCollectionView() {
  let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, 
  collectionViewLayout: layout)
  collectionView.register(StateCollectionViewCell.self, 
  forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "stateCell")
  collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  collectionView.delegate = self
  collectionView.dataSource = self

  view.addSubview(collectionView)
   }

   }

  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, 
  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  //Mark: - Specifying the number of sections in the collectionView
  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
   return 1
  }

  //Mark: - Specifying the number of cells in given section
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return states.count

  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stateCell", for: indexPath)as! stateCollectionViewCell
cell.awakeFromNib()
return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let stateCell = cell as! StateCollectionViewCell
stateCell.stateCell.text = states[indexPath.row]

  }

 }
```

Comment: Try this github [link](https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout/blob/master/KTCenterFlowLayout.m)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, but wanted to be simple, like changes in my current code. For the link, you provided I'll need to add pods and make many changes. So kept it aside. @AdityaSrivastava

Comment: @iDeveloper Just because some UI interface looks simple, does not mean the process of making it happen is simple. And simple can be defined in many ways, simple for some expert might not be simple for somebody who has never done it before. This is however an example of a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout as Aditya linked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the easiest way you can accomplish this is to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and make change to the attributes, it can not be done within the viewController. Because I have just written a similar custom layout to do this and make it a pod, maybe it([github link](https://github.com/Phelthas/LXMWaterfallLayout/blob/master/LXMWaterfallLayout/LXMWaterfallLayout/LXMHeaderFooterFlowLayout.swift)) can help.